$| |x + y|^p - |x|^p | \leq \epsilon |x|^p + C |y|^p$
I want to demonstrate that: Let $1 < p < \infty$; for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $C = C(\epsilon) \geq 1$ such that for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$, we have
$$ | |x + y|^p - |x|^p | \leq \epsilon |x|^p + C |y|^p.$$
I encountered this question while reading an article by Brézis, where, under certain conditions,
$$\lim_n \, ( ||f_n||_p^p - ||f_n - f||_p^p ) = ||f||_p^p.$$
However, the inequality above was simply stated, and I'm struggling to understand why it holds.
My thoughts are that it might be derived from some inequalities involving the derivatives of monotone functions.
Thank you for any insights.

Dividing everything with $|x|^p$ and denoting $z=y/x$, we can equivalently express it as $\left| |1+z|^p - 1 \right| \le \epsilon + C|z|^p$

First, as noted by Euclid, by homogeneity, it suffices to deal with the case $y=1$. Intuitively, the $\varepsilon$ terms is a good bound when $y$ is close to $0$ and the $C\lvert y\rvert^p$ when $y$ is far way from $0$.
Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. By continuity at $0$ of the map $y\mapsto \lvert 1+y\rvert^p-1$, there exists $y_0>0$ such that if $\lvert y\rvert\leqslant y_0$, then $\lvert\lvert 1+y\rvert^p-1\rvert\leqslant \varepsilon$.
Now let $y$ be such that $\lvert y\rvert>y_0$. Then
\begin{align}
\lvert\lvert 1+y\rvert^p-1\rvert&\leqslant \left(1+ \lvert y\rvert\right)^p+1\\
&\leqslant\left(\frac{\lvert y\rvert}{y_0}+ \lvert y\rvert\right)^p+ 
\frac{\lvert y\rvert^p}{y_0^p}\\
&=\left(\left(\frac 1{y_0}+1\right)^p+\frac 1{y_0^p }\right)\lvert y\rvert^p.
\end{align}
In both cases,
$$
\lvert\lvert 1+y\rvert^p-1\rvert\leqslant \varepsilon+\underbrace{\left(\left(\frac 1{y_0}+1\right)^p+\frac 1{y_0^p }\right)}_{C(\varepsilon)}\lvert y\rvert^p.
$$

We will be using the above comment about the equivalence of your inequality to the inequality $f(z):=||1+z|^p-1|\le \epsilon+C|z|^p$.
First, assume $z> -1$ as for $z=-a\le-1$ (where $a\ge 1$) we have
$$
f(z)=g(a)=||a-1|^p-1|\le a^p=|z|^p
$$
(note that $g(0)=0$ and consider separately cases $a\le 1$ and $a>1$).
Case $z\ge 0$.
For $z\ge 1$, we trivially have
$$
f(z)=(1+z)^p-1\le (2z)^p-1<2^p z^p.
$$
For $0<z<1$, since $\ln(1+z)\le z$ for $z>-1$, we have
$$
f(z)=(1+z)^p-1=e^{p\ln(1+z)}-1\le e^{pz}-1.
$$
Fix a small $\epsilon>0$, and let $z_*\in(0,1)$ be such that $e^{pz_*}-1=\epsilon$, hence $f(z)\le \epsilon$ for $z\in [0,z_*]$. Now there exists a constant $C'>0$ such that
$$
\max_{z\in[z_*,1]} f(z)\le e^p-1\le C' \min_{z\in[z_*,1]} z^p
=C' z_*^p.
$$
Setting $C=\max(C',2^p,1)$ we ensure that
$$
f(z)\le \epsilon +C |z|^p\text{ for all } z\ge 0\text{ and }z\le -1.
$$
Finally, for $z\in(-1,0)$,
$$
f(z)=1-(1+z)^p\le (1+|z|)^p-1=f(-z)
$$
since for $a=-z\in[0,1]$ by Jensen's inequality ($p>1$, so $x^p$ isconvex)
$$
\frac{(1+a)^p+(1-a)^p}2\ge \frac{(1+a)+(1-a)}2=1
$$
and thus the result follows from the case $z\in(0,1)$.
